# Cannot convert matrix from S apply regression results into dataframe (R)

Tags: r, sapply

I am trying to perform multiple regression analyses and then extract the coefficients to store each models results together as one dataframe. The regression works perfectly, however afterwards I am left with a matrix object that seemingly cannot be converted to a dataframe. I have tried multiple combinations `as.data.frame()` `rbind()` `rbindlist` `melt()` and `cbind()`, but nothing seems to mitigate this problem.

Below is an example using the mtcars dataset of the regressions I perform via the `sapply` function. I intend for the result (df) to be just a dataframe version of the output I currently have, except this output cannot be manipulated properly as it is in matrix form, not a dataframe. Wrapping this output with `as.data.frame()` merely produces a list object.

```
var_list <- mtcars %>% select(cyl,wt) %>% names()

iterate <- sapply(var_list,function(k){

mod <- lm(data=mtcars, paste("mpg ~ ",k,":factor(drat)",sep = ""))
rbind(coef(mod))

})
```

Is there any way to store `sapply` regression coefficient results in one dataframe? I have seen it suggested elsewhere that similar issues may emerge centered around the "attributes" of the created objects, but it is unclear how to resolve this.

**EDIT**

My intention is to perform the above within another `sapply` function, with another list of outcome variables within the regression. I will then create `ggplot` graphs for each outcome variable, using the data for each regression. I would therefore need something like the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

outcome_var_list = mtcars %>% select(qsec,hp) %>% names()
var_list = mtcars %>% select(cyl,wt) %>% names()

iterate <- sapply(outcome_var_list,function(x){(sapply(var_list,function(k){

mod <- lm(data=mtcars, paste(x," ~ ",k,":factor(drat)",sep = ""))

mod_df = as.data.frame(coef(mod)))

})
#using rownames and coefficient as placeholder names for the actual column names
mod_df %>% ggplot(aes(x = rownames(mod_df), y= coefficient))
})
```

Yet this does not work because I cannot return a df within the sapply function. Am I approaching this the wrong way? Is there an alternative way to perform the regression for a list of independent variables WITHIN a list of dependent variables, extract the data and generate all the plots?

Comment: You got a matrix with column names. Why wouldn't `as.data.frame(iterate)` give you what you want? Are you unaware of the rather basic fact that a data.frame IS just a list with some special attributes?

Comment: This is helpful. I see that using as.data.frame outside of the function does indeed yield the dataframe, so thank you for that. My questions are why it cannot be done within the dataframe? This would make for more flexible data manipulation.

Comment: I don’t think the rbind does anything. `sapply` is returning a matrix unless you set SIMPLIFY as FALSE. You could just wrap as.data.frame around the sapply.

Comment: @IRTFM I had a play around with it, and the only difference is that `rbind` drops the row names, whereas `coef(model)` by itself keeps them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As IRTFM said, using `as.data.frame` (or indeed `as_tibble`) converts the matrix into a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you. This indeed solves the problem of not being able to store the output, but my goal is to create the dataframe within the sapply function, as I need to feed this output to another function (which is wrapped around it). Is this possible or can only the final output be converted to a dataframe, per your solution?

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect my lingering concern